# How to set the column width to either size of the text/*/Auto in WPF using c# code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I wanted to create datagrids in code behind which will be added in other areas (for example, every tabitem would have a datagrid). However, everytime I keep on getting the length of the column width very small where it is just hard to read the data in the datagrid. I looked into other Datagrid tables that I have and copied the same steps that are in the XAML, did not work. Even, I sacrificed using the code behind and just added the datagrid in XAML and used the same settings, same result.

My XAML is following User control:

```
<UserControl>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DockPanel Background="#A0A1A2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False">
     ...........
      <TabControl>
      (tabitem will be generated through loop with adding datagrids into the tabitem in code behind)
      </TabControl>
     </DockPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    dt_grid1 = new DataGrid();
    dt_grid2 = new DataGrid();

    InitializeComponent();

    // Setting up the Datagrids:
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Datagrid1:
        dt_grid1.CanUserAddRows = false;
        dt_grid1.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
        dt_grid1.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
        dt_grid1.CanUserResizeColumns = false;
        dt_grid1.CanUserResizeRows = false;
        dt_grid1.CanUserSortColumns = false;
        dt_grid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dt_grid1.IsReadOnly = true;
        dt_grid1.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        dt_grid1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        dt_grid1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        dt_grid1.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
        //dt_grid1.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(50, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

        // Datagrid2:
        dt_grid2.CanUserAddRows = false;
        dt_grid2.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
        dt_grid2.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
        dt_grid2.CanUserResizeColumns = false;
        dt_grid2.CanUserResizeRows = false;
        dt_grid2.CanUserSortColumns = false;
        dt_grid2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dt_grid2.IsReadOnly = true;
        dt_grid2.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        dt_grid2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        dt_grid2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        dt_grid2.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
        //dt_grid2.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(50, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    });
```

The issue that I have with Datagrid is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Managed to fix the issue to this  `<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">` but I can't understand why

Answer (score 0):

you can set  datagrid itself (not the Dockpanel) property ColumnWidth="*", this will make all Columns in equal size

Comment: Thank you for the response. so you are saying if I removed the dockpanel and set the ColumnWidth to * then it will fix the width of the columns?

Comment: You're Welcome! you can use dockpanel if you wnat to docking  elements to the left, right, top, bottom... (so keep it if so), but for  datagrid Columns you need to set the datagrid  property , in this case it is "ColumnWidth" //ColumnWidth = "*" you can replace  * with a number according to your preference.